# Can't run Homebrew: Cask 'x48' definition is invalid

Tags: homebrew, x11

Running any `brew` command gives me

> Error: Cask 'x48' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':x11'

Because of this I can't even run `brew doctor` to get information on how to address the error.

How do I proceed? What do I need to do to get past this error and get Homebrew working again?

Comment: FWIW `rm -rf "$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/x48"` seems to have done the trick. I don't know if that's the "correct" solution or not; but I don't (yet) see any adverse consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Still had that issue, so tried to deleted this file:

```
rm -rf "$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/x48.rb
```